# sql query to split columns as per two attributes

Tags: sql, oracle, substr

I have a table say A and it has only one column say DATA.

```
DATA
-----
x=1;y=2;z=3
x=4;y=5;z=6
x=14;y=15;z=16;a=25
```

I want the result as below:

```
x         y          z        a 
--------------------------------
1         2          3        0
4         5          6        0
14        15         16       25
```

I am using toad for query processing.

Comment: oracle version? 10+?

Comment: Are there always only 3 values?

Comment: @BrianDeMilia Sometime it is more than 3. I will edit my question accordingly.

Comment: @AnkurVerma I understood the question perfectly, and you'll always find someone here to just give you a complete answer to whatever question you ask, no matter how easy it would be to find through Google, or through the documentation. I just feel that you would be better served by reviewing the Oracle SQL documentation, which gives you an excellent list of string functions and what they are used for. Btw it is always beneficial to ask, "Am I going to be the first person who has ever wanted to know this?" If not, the answer is certainly already out there.

Comment: @DavidAldridge You are right. But this goes for everything, you are not always the first person who has that question for every case so this philosophy does not help. If everybody would be thinking like this only then I guess stackoverflow is also not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested in 12c. First I split data by ';' and then by '='.

```
      with dat (data) as
          (
          select 'x=1;y=2;z=3' from dual union
          select 'x=4;y=5;z=6' from dual
          )
          select 
          REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(data,'[^;]+',1,1),'[^=]+',1,2) as x,
          REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(data,'[^;]+',1,2),'[^=]+',1,2) as y,
          REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(data,'[^;]+',1,3),'[^=]+',1,2) as z
          from dat
```

Output

```
          X Y Z
          1 2 3
          4 5 6
```

Comment: Perfect..Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should use NVL, as OP wants zero in case of NULL values.

Comment: Yep. But that wasn't in original post. Anyways OP can modify it as per his convenience. Thanks for the tip and examples of instr and substr. Always good to learn something.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your table is not normalized. You should store them in different columns rather than storing in a single column as delimited string. Read [Normalization](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Normalization). It should be a permanent solution to fix the **design**.

Anyway, as a workaround, without changing the design, you could do as demonstrated below:

If the pattern is fixed, then you could use **SUBSTR**.

```
SQL> WITH DATA(str) AS(
  2  SELECT 'x=1;y=2;z=3' FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 'x=4;y=5;z=6' FROM dual
  4  )
  5  SELECT substr(str, 3, 1) a,
  6         substr(str, 7, 1) b,
  7         substr(str, 11, 1) c
  8  FROM DATA;

A B C
- - -
1 2 3
4 5 6

SQL>
```

**Update**

If the pattern is not fixed, then use **SUBSTR** and **INSTR**.

```
SQL> WITH DATA(str) AS
  2    ( SELECT 'x=1;y=2;z=3' FROM dual
  3    UNION ALL
  4    SELECT 'x=4;y=5;z=6' FROM dual
  5    UNION ALL
  6    SELECT 'x=14;y=15;z=16;A=25' FROM dual
  7    )
  8  SELECT NVL(SUBSTR(str
  9    ||';', instr(str
 10    ||';', '=', 1, 1) +1, instr(str
 11    ||';', ';', 1, 1) - instr(str
 12    ||';', '=', 1, 1) -1), '0') a,
 13    NVL(SUBSTR(str
 14    ||';', instr(str
 15    ||';', '=', 1, 2) +1, instr(str
 16    ||';', ';', 1, 2) - instr(str
 17    ||';', '=', 1, 2) -1), '0') b,
 18    NVL(SUBSTR(str
 19    ||';', instr(str
 20    ||';', '=', 1, 3) +1, instr(str
 21    ||';', ';', 1, 3) - instr(str
 22    ||';', '=', 1, 3) -1), '0') c,
 23    NVL(SUBSTR(str
 24    ||';', instr(str
 25    ||';', '=', 1, 4) +1, instr(str
 26    ||';', ';', 1, 4) - instr(str
 27    ||';', '=', 1, 4) -1), '0') d
 28  FROM DATA;

A B C D
- - - -
1 2 3 0
4 5 6 0
1 1 1 2
4 5 6 5
```

You could use **Regular expressions**, which would look a shorter code, however, simple **SUBTR and INSTR will be faster than regular expressions**.

Comment: I cannot do normalization on this column because the column is dynamic and it is not that x=1 will come , it can also happen that data will come as below : x=new_data;y=good;z=well done So I cannot use substr

Comment: Looks elegant but it will break if we get more than 1 digit number. But for the given scenarios it is perfect.

Comment: @AnkurVerma No proble, see the update. Use SUBSTR and INSTR to dynamically extract the data. It will be faster than regular expression.

Comment: @Utsav Yes, OP updated his question. I updated my answer too. It won't break now as INSTR will dynamically find the position, no hard-coding of position.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions that do not rely on the data being in a given order:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dc3fc/9)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE A ( DATA ) AS
          SELECT 'x=1;y=2;z=3' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'y=5;z=6;x=4' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'x=14;y=15;z=16;a=25' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'y=9;a=4' FROM DUAL
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( DATA, 'x=(\d+)', 1, 1, 'i', 1 ) AS X,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( DATA, 'y=(\d+)', 1, 1, 'i', 1 ) AS Y,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( DATA, 'z=(\d+)', 1, 1, 'i', 1 ) AS Z,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( DATA, 'a=(\d+)', 1, 1, 'i', 1 ) AS A
FROM   A
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dc3fc/9/0)**:

```
|      X |  Y |      Z |      A |
|--------|----|--------|--------|
|      1 |  2 |      3 | (null) |
|      4 |  5 |      6 | (null) |
|     14 | 15 |     16 |     25 |
| (null) |  9 | (null) |      4 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
WITH POSITIONS AS (
  SELECT DATA,
         INSTR( DATA, 'x=' ) AS X,
         INSTR( DATA, ';', INSTR( DATA, 'x=' ) ) AS X_SEP,
         INSTR( DATA, 'y=' ) AS Y,
         INSTR( DATA, ';', INSTR( DATA, 'y=' ) ) AS Y_SEP,
         INSTR( DATA, 'z=' ) AS Z,
         INSTR( DATA, ';', INSTR( DATA, 'z=' ) ) AS Z_SEP,
         INSTR( DATA, 'a=' ) AS A,
         INSTR( DATA, ';', INSTR( DATA, 'a=' ) ) AS A_SEP
  FROM   A
)
SELECT CASE
          WHEN X = 0     THEN NULL
          WHEN X_SEP = 0 THEN TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR( DATA, X+2 ) )
                         ELSE TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR( DATA, X+2, X_SEP-X-2 ) )
          END
          AS X,
        CASE
          WHEN Y = 0     THEN NULL
          WHEN Y_SEP = 0 THEN TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR( DATA, Y+2 ) )
                         ELSE TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR( DATA, Y+2, Y_SEP-Y-2 ) )
          END
          AS Y,
        CASE
          WHEN Z = 0     THEN NULL
          WHEN Z_SEP = 0 THEN TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR( DATA, Z+2 ) )
                         ELSE TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR( DATA, Z+2, Z_SEP-Z-2 ) )
          END
          AS Z,
        CASE
          WHEN A = 0     THEN NULL
          WHEN A_SEP = 0 THEN TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR( DATA, A+2 ) )
                         ELSE TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR( DATA, A+2, A_SEP-A-2 ) )
          END
          AS A
FROM    POSITIONS
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dc3fc/9/1)**:

```
|      X |  Y |      Z |      A |
|--------|----|--------|--------|
|      1 |  2 |      3 | (null) |
|      4 |  5 |      6 | (null) |
|     14 | 15 |     16 |     25 |
| (null) |  9 | (null) |      4 |
```